# Recommend or find a tool, library or open source of antivirus apps on Android platform？

Tags: android, open-source, antivirus

I need some antivirus apps which are open sources on Android platform.
Thanks!

Comment: try asking this question over at http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ask at android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might take a look at android-av (https://github.com/zaventh/android-av). It's a proof-of-concept framework for Android security. It's the only solution I was able to find.